# How do I add an "install" target to a Xamarin.UWP .csproj file?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, msbuild, xamarin.uwp

I am trying to build and launch a Xamarin.Forms UWP application from the command line. Using the developer command prompt for Visual Studio 2019 I run the following command:

```
msbuild -t:build "project path\SimToools.UWP.csproj" && msbuild -t:install "project path\SimTools.UWP.csproj"
```

Although once I run this command, the build is completed successfully, then I'm met with this error in the command prompt as shown in the image below:

[image]

How do I add an install target in the SimTools.UWP.csproj file for MSBuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I add an “install” target to a Xamarin.UWP .csproj file?

Derive from above description, you have build the app successfully. But it throw error when install the app. msbuild  does not support install the UWP app. And for installing UWP app you may need use WinAppDeployCmd.exe command tool to approach. For more detail please refer [Install apps with the WinAppDeployCmd.exe tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/install-universal-windows-apps-with-the-winappdeploycmd-tool) document.

Comment: I will give this implementation a try thank you very much! Although one question I have is if the windows executable file does not support runs directly, how does the application launch?

Comment: You could only sideload the app then launch it.

Comment: I can't figure out how to install the appx package with WinAppDeployCmd, is there another approach that can be used to install the package purely locally and not remotely?

Comment: Sure, you could use power shell to install uwp app, please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/add-appxpackage?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

Comment: Thanks Nico! That works for install and uninstall.