# How to build and run Xamarin.UWP application from command line?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, msbuild

How do I build and run a Xamarin.UWP application from the command line? I want it to be so that the app builds and runs the same way as the green run button in the Visual Studio 2019 GUI.

Additional notes:

I've tried opening the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt and trying the following implementations.

```
msbuild -t:build "PATH_TO_PROJECT\SimTools.UWP.csproj"
```

Although when I run the executable that gets generated, it gives me this error:
[image]
as well as
[image]

Additionally, I've tried doing

```
msbuild -t:build "PATH_TO_PROJECT\SimTools.UWP.csproj" && msbuild -t:install "PATH_TO_PROJECT\SimTools.UWP.csproj"
```

And although it builds successfully, it says that there is no target for "install" and I do not know how to add that to the .csproj file as I've asked over at [How do I add an "install" target to a Xamarin.UWP .csproj file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67235948/how-do-i-add-an-install-target-to-a-xamarin-uwp-csproj-file).

Comment: I have replied the similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67235948/how-do-i-add-an-install-target-to-a-xamarin-uwp-csproj-file), please refer.

Comment: And please note, UWP execute file does not support run directly.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT once I am able to install the application, how can I run it?

Comment: You could run it with click the app's icon in the start menu.

Comment: Is there any way I can just run the application from the command line once it has installed?

Comment: Sure, you could also use powershell to launch installed app. for example `start shell:AppsFolder\$(Get-StartApps "appname" | select -ExpandProperty AppId)`